# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space to find all strings of length n

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I want to generate all possible strings of length n with alphabets a,b, and c .. I am getting this error `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`: Java heap space. my heap size is 512m . Can you suggst me alternatives for this ..

Comment: What is the length you try to find all permutations of?

Comment: Why are you using BigInteger everywhere?  How big do your numbers get?

Comment: maximum is 3^30 . Alternatives would be of great help . i want to remove and find the count of substrings not containing "ABC" .

Comment: So you're asking for (3**30) * 30 bytes of storage.  Have you figured out how much that is?

Comment: @HotLicks yes i have. do u have any alternatives of how do i process my code to find all permuatations.

Comment: Just the list of all possible 30-byte strings is going to require more storage than is present on any non-supercomputer, and will take probably years to compute.  I think you need to go back and decide what you really want to do.

Comment: @Dinesh Wait you've already figured out that you'd need about 190Tb of memory assuming every string was 1byte long but you still asked this question? You'll need to use math for that - not a hard problem at all if I understand it right (subtract the number of permutations of ABC from the number of permutations of your whole alphabet)+

Comment: @DineshKukreja so do you want to count those strings or list them? if the latter, do you want to count strings not containing **substring** "ABC"? for example do you want to count "ACBAC" and "ACCAB" but not "ABCAC"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counting Strings not containing substring "ABC" can be solved with dynamic programming.

First, lets name the number of all strings of length n as `S(n)`. Note that `S(n)` is easy to compute. `S(n) = pow(size_of_the_alphabet,n)`

Let's name the number all strings containing "ABC" of length n as `A(n)` and let's name the number of all strings having first ocurrence of "ABC" on k-th position as `A(n,k)`

Now note that:
`A(n,k) = (S(k-1) - A(k-1)) * S(n - k - 3)` (since k is the first position where "ABC" occurs, each of these strings has a substring without "ABC" before this position and any substring after the first "ABC").

Note that `A(n) = sum A(n,k) for k in [0..n-3]`

So now we can calculate `A(n)` computing each value of `A(n)` starting from 0.

Base case is simple, as `A(n) = 0 for n = 0,1,2`

`A(3) = (S(0) - A(0))*S(0) = 1` (namely "ABC")

etc..

Once you have `A(n)` you can get the number you're looking for using the formula `S(n) - A(n)`.

Pseudojava pseudocode:

```
public class Counter {


    public int count(int aSize, int n) {
        long[] a = new long[n+1]; // n + 1 elements since a[i] contains # of strings containing "ABC"
        a[0] = 0;
        a[1] = 0;
        a[2] = 0;


        for (int i = 3; i <= n; ++i){
            long sum = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k <= i-3; ++k) {
                sum += (pow(aSize, k) - a[k]) * pow(aSize, i - k - 3);
            }
            a[i] = sum;
        }
        return a[n];

    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        int aSize = 3; //size of the alphabet
        int n = 30; // length of the strings

        //final result
        long result = pow(aSize, n) - count(aSize, n);


    }
}
```

Running time is `O(n^2)`, assuming pow is O(1). If it's not then you can save some time precalculating S(i).

Space requirement is `O(n)`.

Note that this computes number of all strings with length == n. If you want length <= n then the modification is obvious (you just sum all elements in a).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wasnt able to figure out how to use dynamic programming . thanks for the help .

Comment: @DineshKukreja no problem. just watch out for overflows. it probably should be long instead of int (or even BigDecimal). I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 5):

The number of strings you are currently computing is

```
3^30 =                205 891 132 094 649
```

Which is quite a lot...

Knowing that each String contains three bytes:

```
3^30 * 3 =            617 673 396 283 947
```

Plus the 32-bit or 64-bit pointers of the two dimensional array.

```
3^30 * (3 + 4) =    1 441 237 924 662 540  // 32-bit Java VM
3^30 * (3 + 8) =    2 264 802 453 041 140  // 64-bit Java VM
```

Which is

```
2 109 261 GB = 2059 TB     // 64-bit JVM
```

I guess that is the problem.

---

With your limit of 500 MB you can solve this equation:

```
  3^x * (3 + 8) = 524 288 000
            3^x = 47662545
              x = log(47662545) / log(3)
              x = 7 / 0.477121254719662
              x = 14.67
```

So, if I forgot nothing, your tests should work for `n <= 14`. Of course, it won't work until you delete this code:

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
for (char[] permutation : table) {
    result.add(new String(permutation));
}
```

This code duplicates all the data! Which means that you need twice the amount of memory. Try to print it immediately.

Comment: @Chris: Exactly. (I like this comment :D)

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux this proves how dumb u are ?

Comment: @DineshKukreja: I guess your comment proves how dump you are. Never though this might be humour? Why do you think Chris his comment got 3 upvotes?

Answer (score 1):

I noted in your comment you have a different question.  You want to find all the strings of length 30 with a-z which don't contains a-c.  This is the count of all the string of length 30 which are d-z. The count is (26-3)^30.

```
System.out.printf("%,d%n", BigInteger.valueOf(26-3).pow(30));
```

prints

```
71,094,348,791,151,363,024,389,554,286,420,996,798,449
```

---

Instead of remembering every string, you can encode every possible String as a number. In your case you can use a `long`.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    String letters = "abc";
    int len = 30;
    long combinations = (long) Math.pow(letters.length(), len);
    System.out.printf("There are %,d strings%n", combinations);
    for (long i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        System.out.println(fromLong(i, letters, len));
    System.out.println("... some numbers skipped ...");
    for (long i = combinations-10; i < combinations; i++)
        System.out.println(fromLong(i, letters, len));
}

public static String fromLong(long n, String letters, int len) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        sb.append(letters.charAt((int) (n % letters.length())));
        n /= letters.length();
    }
    return sb.reverse().toString();
}
```

prints

```
There are 205,891,132,094,649 strings
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaac
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaba
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabb
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabc
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaca
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaacb
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaacc
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabaa
... some numbers skipped ...
cccccccccccccccccccccccccccbcc
ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccaa
ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccab
ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccac
ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccba
ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccbb
ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccbc
ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccca
cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccb
cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
```

This can print every possible String from 0 to 3^30-1.  You don't need to store all the encoded values because you know all the possible values are in a continuous range.

Comment: Wow, does it work? `main(String... args)`. I didn't know we can use varargs for the main method. Nice. However, +1.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to compute the strings or count the strings?

EDIT: I see from the later comment that you know how many Strings you're talking about:
<del>If you are only counting, that's a standard permutation closed form: `26^n` = 26 raised to the nth power (assuming that you're only using lower case alphabet from 'a' to 'z').</del>

If you are truly trying to enumerate every string, I strongly recommend that you ensure that you do not retain a reference to each `String`.  If you end up with a dangling reference to each of those Strings, you're going to run out of memory after about six characters.